# Populating a Matrix by doing Calculations along the Diagonal

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix n*n with values along its diagonal. I would like to create a new matrix by multiplying elements of the diagonal matrix `b`, corresponding to the position of the elements along the diagonal.

For example, say I have a 4*4 matrix:

```
set.seed(5)
b <- diag(sample(4))
colnames(b) <- rownames(b) <- c("AAA" , "BBB" , "CCC" , "DDD")
```

Giving matrix `b`:

```
    AAA BBB CCC DDD
AAA   2   0   0   0
BBB   0   3   0   0
CCC   0   0   1   0
DDD   0   0   0   4
```

I would like to compute matrix `d` by multiplying as follows:

```
b[AAA , AAA] = 2 * 2 = 4
```

and

```
b[AAA , BBB] = 2 * 3 = 6
```

The end result should give:

```
    AAA BBB CCC DDD
AAA   4   6   2   8
BBB   6   9   3  12
CCC   2   3   1   4
DDD   8  12   4  16
```

Is there an efficient code that can do this without having to do this by hand? This would not be possible if the matrix is very large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is the *outer product* of the diagonal. You can get this by doing:

```r
outer(diag(b), diag(b))
    AAA BBB CCC DDD
AAA   4   6   2   8
BBB   6   9   3  12
CCC   2   3   1   4
DDD   8  12   4  16
```

or

```r
 diag(b) %o% diag(b)
    AAA BBB CCC DDD
AAA   4   6   2   8
BBB   6   9   3  12
CCC   2   3   1   4
DDD   8  12   4  16
```